# Google Pie Chart size option

Tags: google-visualization, pie-chart

I'm using the [Google Pie Chart](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/piechart) to visualize some data. My problem is that the size always gets limited to 200px height. I've tried to figure out the different options, but to no avail. Even if my original container (chart_div) is set to a height of 500px, the automatically generated child container is limited to 200px in height:

```
<div id="chart_div" style="width: 900px; height: 500px; position: relative;">
    <div style="position: relative; width: 400px; height: 200px;" dir="ltr">
        <div style="position: absolute; left: 0px; top: 0px; width: 100%; height: 100%;">
            <svg width="400" height="200" style="overflow: hidden;">
                 ...
        </div>
    <div>
</div>
```

I've tried adding some options like `chartArea:{left:20,top:0,width:"100%",height:"100%"}`, but that only pushed the legend out of the div, and didn't effect the sizing of the divs.

Comment: Running the sample code for the pie chart works for me. The size is dynamically generated depending on what I add as my height. Maybe you have your div contained in some other tag that is restricting it?

Comment: You might be right. I'm trying to add the pie chart to a site with horrible design, but it's strange that the parent containers get the correct size, and it's the autogenerated div that is restricting. I don't understand where it gets its size from...

Comment: The `div` it is contained in is 400 by 200. Default behavior is to match the size of the containing `div`. Unless you change the size of the `div`, your pie chart (no matter what the options) will be limited to 400 x 200.

Comment: @jmac I didn't create the div that's 400 by 200. I only created the div with the id `chart_div` which is 900 by 500. Everything inside that div is auto-generated.

Comment: Are you running the code from google playground as it is? If not, please give us the exact code (full HTML & JS) for the page causing the problem so that we can actually test it on our own. Otherwise we are stuck guessing what's happening...